# Does anyone know a crowdsourcing plugin that can support the following use case?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My use case is the following - I haven't had much success with the plugin I am using for crowdsourcing.

Pre-sell a t-shirt to many buyers until it reaches a goal price and then charge all customers. If it does not reach the goal price in the allotted time, refund all users or cancel their pre-authorisations.

Comment: You mean crowdfunding? There are a few plugins if you search for that, but I haven't used any myself to recommend them. Or this should be doable with WooCommerce: you'd just have to modify the payment providers to do a pre-auth and not a full take payment. If this t-shirt is a one-off I'd then do the admin manually rather than trying to code that up probably.

Comment: Thanks @Rup. L'll look into the woocommerce pre-order plugin as well.